# Divide $\mathbb R$ into non-overlapping intervals

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Two subsets of $\mathbb R$ are said to be ***non-overlapping***, if they have no interior points in common.

A collection of non-degenerate closed and mutually non-overlapping intervals $\mathcal C$ is said to be an ***exact partition*** of $\mathbb R,$ if  $\displaystyle\bigcup\mathcal C=\mathbb R.$

> It's easy to check that every exact partition of $\mathbb R$ is a countable set, thus one may be inclined to say that we can always express an exact partition of $\mathbb R$ as the following form: $$\mathcal C=\left\{[x_i,x_{i+1}]|\ i\in\mathbb Z\right\}.\tag{1}$$

So we have the following plausible claim:

> **Claim 1:** Every exact partition of $\mathbb R$ could be expressed in the form $(1).$

If the claim above is correct, then for any $a<b\in \mathbb R,$ only finite  intervals in $\mathcal C$ would "fall into" $(a,b].$  ie., the set $\left\{X\in \mathcal C|\ X\subset (a,b]\right\}$ is finite.

> **Inference of claim 1:** If $\mathcal C$ is an exact partition of $\mathbb R,$ then for any $a<b\in\mathbb R,$ the set $\left\{X\in \mathcal C|\ X\subset (a,b]\right\}$ is finite.

However, here comes the counterexample:$(0,1]=\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Big[{1\over n+1},{1\over n}\Big],$ while $\mathcal C:=\left\{[n,n+1]|\ n\in \mathbb Z,\ n\leqslant -1\right\}\cup \left\{\Big[\displaystyle{1\over n+1},{1\over n}\Big]\bigg|\ n\in\mathbb N\right\}\cup \left\{[n,n+1]|\ n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ is an exact partition of $\mathbb R.$  So the claim 1 is actually not  correct.

**Question:** What requirements should be added to the definition of  exact partition $\mathcal C,$ so that $(1)$ would be true?

Comment: You example is an exact partition not of R, but of (0,1].

Comment: @William Elliot: Thanks for pointing out. I've added some information.

Comment: The intervals must not accumulate somewhere. In order to do this you can require that $$\liminf_{i \to \infty} |x_{i+1}-x_i| >0$$

Comment: @Crostul: The intervals are typically not naturally put in a sequence, so I think it's better to just say that the infimum of lengths is positive.

Comment: @Crostul: It's Okay, but I'd like to say that $\mathcal C:=\left\{[-\ln(n+1),-\ln n]|\ n\in\mathbb N\right\}\cup \left\{[\ln n,\ln (n+1)]|n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ also satisfies $(1),$ while $\inf_{I\in \mathcal C} |I|=0.$

Comment: @Crostul Not only is that not sufficient, but *no* condition involving only the lengths of the intervals can characterize OP's condition (1). Given any countable collection of lengths whose sum is infinite, we can just index them by $\mathbb Z$ in some way and then place the intervals on the real line in that order.

Comment: How is that a counterexample?  It is not required that the x's are in increasing order.

Comment: @William Elliot: Actually, in formula $(1),$  since the intervals in an exact partition of $\mathbb R$ should be non-degenerate, we have  $x_{i+1}> x_i,\ \forall\ i\in \mathbb Z.$